# <tbody> is inheriting the width of the first column of the header

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to make a table that a) can be sorted by column and b) has a scroll bar for the body while keeping the header static. To create my table (I'm still learning HTML and JavaScript) I was based on these examples: 
[Body scroll](http://jsfiddle.net/FeU3T/2/) and [Table Sorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/). So my code looks very similar to those.

The content is generated upon loading from a database and that works just fine. If I just use the sort functionality in my code it works fine too, so does if I implement the scroll only to the body. The problem arises when I try to merge both of them. What happens is that the header is displayed just fine while the body is displayed as if the its parent container had the width of the first column only.

```
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
  <thead class="fixedHeader">
    <tr>
     <th><span class="text">Group</span></th>
     <th><span class="text">Activities</span></th>
     <th><span class="text">Classes</span></th>
     <th><span class="text">Discussions</span></th>
     <th><span class="text">Happy Hours</span></th>
     <th><span class="text">Parties</span></th>
     <th><span class="text">Workshops</span></th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="scrollContent">
    <tr>
      <td>Austin TNG</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><iframe iconcolor="#0000FF" src="SVG/Discussionx.svg" style="height:30px;width:30px;border:0px;color:white">1</iframe></td>
      <td><iframe iconcolor="#0000FF" src="SVG/HHG.svg" style="height:30px;width:30px;border:0px;color:white">2</iframe></td>
      .....
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>...</td>
     ....
    </tr>
    ....
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The CSS for this portion is:

```
div.table-scroll{
  height:100%;
  width:85%;
  float:left;
  overflow:hidden; 
}

table.tablesorter {
    font-family:arial;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin:10px 0pt 15px;
    font-size: 90%;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height:auto;
    text-align: center;
    /*table-layout: fixed;*/    
}

table.tablesorter thead tr .header {
    background-image: url(bg.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
    cursor: pointer;
    height:30px;
}

table.tablesorter thead tr th {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    font-size: 120%;
    padding: 4px;
    height:30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

table.tablesorter tbody.scrollContent {
    height: 85%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    overflow:auto;
}

table.tablesorter tbody td {
    color: #3D3D3D;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height:30px;    
}
```

As you can see the scrollbar shows up right where the first column ends. It should be when the "workshop" column ends.

[image]

Any idea what could be causing this? The code in the "inspect element" section seems right to me, this is the way my browser sees the code being generated by Javascript. If anyone can give me an idea on where to look at to solve this issue I'd greatly appreciate it.